# Unable to put laptop to sleep after installing AMD driver

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have `HP Probook4540s` laptop with Core i5 processor, 8GiB RAM and an `AMD ATI Radeon HD 7500M/7600M` graphics card of 2 GB and I am running windows 8 pro x64.

Thing is my graphics card driver doesn't seems to work correctly along with my rest system.
I made sure that I have correct drivers:

- Download the driver from HPs site, my entering my product serial
  number and the driver they had for Win 8.
- I Downloaded from AMDs site using (auto detect card functionality)
  and installed the driver.

What happens that when I have AMD graphics driver installed I am unable to put my laptop to sleep my closing it lid down because If I so that and re open it instead of waking up it restart and after restart when windows comes it shows recover blue screen "**your PC ran into a problem.**"

And after analyzing the memory dump file it has been found that the crash order was like this:

```
atikmdag.sys      atikmdag.sys+0                 ATI Radeon Family                                           ATI Radeon Kernel Mode Driver                8.01.01.1331       Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.     C:\Windows\system32\drivers\atikmdag.sys    
dxgmms1.sys     dxgmms1.sys+2c648       Microsoft® Windows® Operating System              DirectX Graphics MMS                6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)                Microsoft Corporation                C:\Windows\system32\drivers\dxgmms1.sys   
ntoskrnl.exe      ntoskrnl.exe+6d27a        Microsoft® Windows® Operating System              NT Kernel & System                6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)                Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe               
watchdog.sys    watchdog.sys+255d        Microsoft® Windows® Operating System              Watchdog Driver                6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)                Microsoft Corporation                C:\Windows\system32\drivers\watchdog.sys
```

It is also sure that the problem is with the Graphics card because if I uninstall all the drivers than no such problems happened and I am able to normal close the lid and put my laptop to sleep and wake it up.

Can anyone tell why this happening is? And how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you contacted HP about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue. If you right click CMD and run as administrator, type: `powercfg -a`.
If you see it complaining about VGAPNP.SYS, then the driver you have for your video card does not support the sleep function and you will have to update your driver.  I have yet to resolve this issue as I am still looking for a proper driver.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser. Since you don;t have a solution to this problem yet, your answer is more suitable as comment, until you find a proper solution to the problem.